# calling on a complex function with onClick (ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I have this chunk of code here (below). It waits for a video to finish playing and then it looks up a cookie, sends that info to a php script through ajax, gets back a url from json, and reloads an iframe with a new url.

So I think you'll agree, it's sorta a lot going on.

Its purpose is to advance ONE forward in a playlist of videos. I am trying to create a button area where a user can click a >> sort of button and go forward. Which is exactly what this function does.

Rather than starting from scratch with a new function,  is there a way to activate all of the above function functionality (ajax and all) when the user clicks that button?

```
<script>

 function ready(player_id)
        {

             $f('play').addEvent('ready', function()
                        {
              $f('play').addEvent('finish', onFinish);
                        });

            function onFinish(play)
                 {

                    var now_video_var = $.cookie('now_video');
                    console.log ('player ' + now_video_var + ' has left the building');
                    var intermediate_integer = parseInt(now_video_var);


                    var request2 = $.ajax({
                        url : "geturl.php",
                        data : {intermediate_integer : intermediate_integer},
                        type : 'post'
                    }).done(function(data) {

                        var gotfrom = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        var NEWURL = gotfrom[1] ;
                        console.log(gotfrom);
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(gotfrom[1]);



             var theiframeforrealyo =    document.getElementById('play');

                     $(theiframeforrealyo).attr("src", "http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + gotfrom[1] +"?api=1&player_id=play&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autoplay=1");


                     var new_video_var = intermediate_integer +1;
                    $.cookie('now_video', new_video_var);
                    console.log ( 'cookie function ok: the cookie is....');
                    console.log ($.cookie('now_video'));

                        });

                    }
                 }
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            //Attach the ready event to the iframe
            $f(document.getElementById('play')).addEvent('ready', ready);
        });



    </script>
```

Comment: Cant you just call your ready function from a click handler attached to your button?

Comment: that would be the easiest answer, yeah. But what function do I call and do I have to re-wrap this to accept a generic call from any element?

Comment: could you tell me what $f is? also, why do you think you have to wrap anything? The argument player_id isnt actually being used in your handler so presumably you can just call ready any time you want eg from a click handler : 

$('#buttonid').click(ready);